# Unable to parse full javascript if statement from within Java using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino, scriptengine

So I posted this question 
[Putting a simple expression language into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285045/putting-a-simple-expression-language-into-java)
and got a great answer about using ScriptEngine to allow the user to write javascript which I did and it seemed to work

But whilst an expression like

```
(artist.length>0 ? artist + '-' :'') + (album.length>0 ? album + '-' :'')
```

works using a full if statement does not

```
if(artist.length>0) {artist + ':-'}   + (album.length>0 ? album + '-' :'')
```

You might ask why Im doing this, well I was hoping I could use an if:else if:else statement and this was a step towards that

Comment: `java != javascript` ...

Comment: @Neal: The OP is asking about JS code that's being run from Java, using JSR-223. Sometimes this kind of context matters, hence why the OP mentioned it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That simply isn't valid javascript.  The

```
<cond> ? <iftrue> : <iffalse>
```

is the 'expression' form of if-else, and returns the value which can be used.

```
if {

} else {

}
```

is the 'statement' version, and is used to execute code, and does NOT return a value.

Comment: thanks you've exposed my javascript ignorance here, so is it possible for me to do the equivalent of if else if else in the expression

Comment: You could nest the expressions, like a ? b : (c ? d : e), which translates to:
If a, then b, else if c, then d, else e

Comment: thanks that worked i.e (albumartist.length>0  ? albumartist :(artist.length>0 ? artist  : ' '))