# How to convert java ScriptEngine code to use Rhino

Tags: java, rhino, scriptengine

I embed javascript expressions into my java prog as follows
[Putting a simple expression language into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285045/putting-a-simple-expression-language-into-java)

But I now realise I need to use Rhino directly rather than ScriptEngine because I need to preserve Java 1.5 compatabiliy, I think I can run the evaluation as folllows

```
Context context = Context.enter();
try {
    Scriptable scope = context.initStandardObjects();
    String result = context.evaluateString(scope, expr, null, 0, null);
    return result
} finally {
    Context.exit();
}
```

but whats the alternative to

```
jsEngine.put(fieldname.getScriptVariable(), value);
```

to map values to variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need to do is the following:

```
Object wrappedObject = Context.javaToJS(yourObjectHere, scope);
ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "yourVariableNameHere", wrappedObject);
```

See the [Expose Java APIs](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/tutorial.html#expose) Rhino example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to be java 1.5 compatible at least use BSF framework from Jakarta project. It is similar to java scripting framework introduced in java 1.6

Comment: Useful to know but my use of javascript is limited to the issue above so Id rather not introduce something else at this point