# Alternative plugin to Javascript for Java to provide a way for user to specify a mask

Tags: java

I'm looking for a scripting language that can be run on a Java VM that would work as a simple scripting language that a user can use for specifying how there filenames are constructed from music metadata. Please see earlier related post of mine [Putting a simple expression language into java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285045/putting-a-simple-expression-language-into-java) where Javascript was recommended, I use this and it works:

i.e I if I have a file containing the following metadata:

```
albumartist=U2
album=Boy
trackno=02
title=Twilight
```

and apply this javascript mask:

```
(albumartist.length>0  ? albumartist +'-' :(artist.length>0 ? artist + '-' : ' ')) + (album.length>0 ? album + '-' :'') + (trackno.length>0 ? trackno + '-' :'')  + title
```

it will output

U2-Boy-02-Twilight

which is great.

But the trouble is the Javascript syntax is **too hard** for the average user.

Can anyone recommend an alternative scripting language I can plugin that gives me simailar functionality but a simpler syntax. For example it would be nice if I could use this kind of syntax instead

```
if(albumartist,albumartist-)else if(artist,artist-)(album,album-)(trackno,trackno)title
```

and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a scripting language I suggest you look into using a template language, like [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) .

Whichever path you choose, be aware of the security implications of accepting user-supplied input and executing it.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using JSON would be a good way to solve your problem. In the example you give, the JSON would look as follows:

```
{
  "albumartist": "U2", 
  "album": "Boy", 
  "trackno": 2, 
  "title": "Twilight"     
}
```

There are numerous JSON to Java parsers available. I use GSON from Google - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

For other parsers and general information about JSON, go to http://www.json.org/

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstand the problem I want the user to be enter a mask that can be applied to some metadata, json doesnt help with this

Comment: sorry, you are right. I did not read the question carefully. and unfortunately I have nothing else to suggest other than writing your own simple scripting language parser, which actually is not all that difficult.

Comment: I want the parser to understand constructs such as if/else and have functions like substring() and uppercase(). IMO this is too difficult (in fact I did have my own parser until moved to using Javascript) and I don't like to reinvent the wheel , so guess I'll have to stick with Javascript unless anything else comes up